# Delete last occurrence of a non-consecutive, duplicate word/phase in a PHP string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

OK, I've been trying to figure this one out for a while, but I can't seem to get it right.  I need to delete the ***last*** occurrence of a non-consecutive, duplicate word/phrase from the **END** of a string.  For example, I want

```
Love in My Antonia Love in
```

and

```
Love in My Antonia Love
```

to become

```
Love in My Antonia
```

I have tried countless patterns without success.  The closest I have gotten to success is this:

```
 preg_replace('/\b(\w{2,})\b(?=.*?\\1)\W*/', ''
```

That deletes the *first* occurrence (rather than the last), rendering:

```
 in My Antonia Love (ORIGINAL: "Love in My Antonia Love")
```

and

```
 My Antonia Love in (ORIGINAL: "Love in My Antonia Love in")
```

Please help!  :)

UPDATE (Nov. 9, 2:00 PM, PST):  I should have clarified that—if at all possible—I would like the solution to remain in the simple, 1-line, compact format that I showed in my example:

```
preg_replace('/\b(\w{2,})\b(?=.*?\\1)\W*/', ''
```

My example already works almost perfectly, except that it deletes the *first* match instead of the *last*.  I was hoping that someone could modestly manipulate my existing code so that it deletes the last match (at the end of the string) instead of the first occurrence.  Is that more complicated than I thought?

Previously, I came up with a version that finds two consecutive, duplicate words/phrases anywhere in a string and replaces them with one:

```
preg_replace('~\b([\S \w]{3,})\K\b(?:\s*\1)+~', '',
```

This makes "pizza pizza" become "pizza" and "I walked to the store I walked to the store" become "I walked to the store."  That's great, and I have already incorporated that solution.  Now, secondarily, I also need "Pizza is the best pizza" to become "Pizza is the best."  Similarly, "Sheep dogs are awesome pets dogs are" should become "Sheep dogs are awesome pets."  So, basically, it does not matter where in the string the first occurrence appears; all that matters is that the occurrence at the **END OF THE STRING** gets deleted.  I hope this brings more clarity.

Comment: What happens if the last word be a duplicate?  E.g. what would `Love in My Anotonia Love Love` become?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, such a situation would be an extreme outlier, so I'm not concerned.  Good question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$s = preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b(\1)$/i', '\\1\\2', $s);
```

Test:

```
$s = "Love in My Antonia Love in";
$s1 = "Love in My Antonia Love";
$s2 = "Love in My Antonia Love Not On End";

echo "Original:\n$s\n";
echo preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b(\1)$/i', '\\1\\2', $s);
echo "\n";
echo "Original:\n$s1\n";
echo preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b(\1)$/i', '\\1\\2', $s1);
echo "\n";
echo "Original:\n$s2\n";
echo preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b(\1)$/i', '\\1\\2', $s2);
```

Output:

```
ZC-MGMT-04:~ jv$ php -q c.php
Original:
Love in My Antonia Love in
Love in My Antonia
Original:
Love in My Antonia Love
Love in My Antonia
Original:
Love in My Antonia Love Not On End
Love in My Antonia Love Not On End
```

====

UPDATE:

Jason suggests slight update to address ' at the end of the word:

```
preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b\b(\1)(\'s)*\b$/i', '\\1\\2')
```

Comment: Your solution successfully changes "Love in My Antonia Love" to "Love in My Antonia", but it does not change "Women in Combat Units Women" to "Women in Combat Units".  Any idea why?

Comment: My bad.  That was only because I had another preg_replace that was conflicting.

Comment: Here's my final, tweaked version that works best because it prevents accidental truncation within words AND prevents 's from being left behind when it is attached to a deleted word: 

preg_replace('/^\b([\w ]+)(.*?)\b\b(\1)(\'s)*\b$/i', '\\1\\2',

Comment: jancha, you may want to edit your answer to incorporate my tweaks.  It's up to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this without regular expressions, by splitting the sentence into component words and then manually checking the last two words:

```
$input = "Love in My Antonia Love in";
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $input);
$last = $words[count($words)-1];
$pattern = "/^(?=.*\b" . $last . "\b.*\b" . $last . "\b).*/";
if ($words[count($words) - 1] != $words[count($words) - 2] &&
    preg_match($pattern, $input, $match)) {
    array_pop($words);
}
$output = implode(" ", $words);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;

Love in My Antonia Love in
Love in My Antonia Love
```

Comment: You are answering your own question but not OP's one

Comment: @splash58 Just because the OP requested regex does not mean it is the best solution here. Wiktor's regex looks pretty complex, and I would not want to maintain or inherit that in an actual code base.

Comment: `I want

Love in My Antonia Love in
and

Love in My Antonia Love
to become

Love in My Antonia`

Comment: Compare with your output

Comment: You are interpreting "duplicate" differently than I am.  I am interpreting that as meaning if the last two words are the same, then we don't replace.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: *I need to delete the last occurrence of a non-consecutive, duplicate word/prase*

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the longest duplicate substring first then remove it from the end of subject string. This could be done using a `preg_match_all` for doing a case-insensitive search then a `preg_replace` for omitting them:

```
$str = 'Love in My Antonia Love in';
preg_match_all('~(\b\w++(?> \w++)*)(?=.*?\b\1)~i', $str, $matches);
$array = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $matches[1]));
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $str = preg_replace("~^.*\K(?<!\s)\s*\b$value~i", '', $str);
}
echo trim($str); // Love in My Antonia
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/phAtO)